# Как отключить select при выбранном option в другом select?

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <div class="custom__select">
        <!-- MODIFIED добавлен id -->
        <select name="select" id="holiday">
          <option value="1">Да</option>
          <option value="2">Нет</option>
          <option value="3">Доп.нагрузка</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="custom__select">
        <!-- MODIFIED добавлен id -->
        <select name="select" id="percentage">
          <option value="">0 %</option>
          <option value="">10 %</option>
          <option value="">20 %</option>
          <option value="">30 %</option>
          <option value="">40 %</option>
          <option value="">50 %</option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

```
var element = document.querySelectorAll('select');

for (var i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
  var choices = new Choices(element[i], {
    searchEnabled: false,
    itemSelectText: '',
    placeholder: true,
    placeholderValue: 1,
  })
```

;
}

Нужно чтобы при значении value = 1 или 2 в первом селекте второй селект отключался полностью, то есть выбор в нем невозможен. Как это реализовать через js или jquery? Еще одна загвоздка, select стилизован при помощи библиотеки choice.js и селекты обработаны с помощью цикла

Что тогда в этом случае нужно делать?

Comment: сделайте воспроизводимый пример. С  choice.js и циклом. )

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отключить select при выбранном option в другом select](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1364127/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-select-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-option-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bc-select)